# Oracle subquery does not see the variable on second level

Tags: oracle

It returns

> "invalid identifier" on "pe.partyid" (level 2).

Can you please advise on how to correct?

```
   update table_x pe
   set pe.taxidnumber =
       (select tin
          from (select tin
                      ,version
                      ,max(version) over(partition by partyid) maxversion
                  from table_y
                 where partyid = pe.partyid)
         where version = maxversion);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle you can use a table alias in an immediate subquery (one level down), but not in more deeply-nested subqueries.

You can go around this with factored subqueries (WITH clause). But in your case, it's not clear why you need a correlated sub-subquery. Move the WHERE condition on matching by `partyid` to the middle query; that way the inner-most query will be uncorrelated, so it will be computed just once. Move the `partyid` check next to `version = maxversion`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
  create global temporary table tempt as select tin, partyid from table_y where rownum < 2;
  insert into tempt select tin, partyid
             from (select tin
                      ,partyid
                      ,version
                      ,max(version) over(partition by partyid) maxversion
                  from table_y
         where version = maxversion);
  merge into table_x t
  using tempt d
  on (t.partyid = d.partyid)
  when matched then update set t.tin = d.tin;
```

Comment: The temporary table is not needed at all. You can use that `select` statement directly in the `merge` statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for comment, I know that but I've posted solution with temp table just to avoid confusin with ORA-30926 in case of updating more columns.